# Git: tag branch and create a new branch from tag

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I have some automated system to tag my `old` branches.
I'm doing that to avoid a big amount of branches.

But sometimes it happens that some of tagged previously branches are needed for my to make some additional changes.

Is there any proper way to work with this tags?

AFAIK, I can create a new branch from these tags like this:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <tag>
```

It looks pretty fine, but...

1) I'm calling tags with the same name as was original name of branch.

2) I want to create a branch with the same name as it was.

It's not possible, because it raises with an error:

```
warning: refname '<branch_name>' is ambiguous.
fatal: A branch named '<branch_name>' already exists.
```

Another thing I want to add is that I expect to remove this tag when a branch was created from it.

Is it possible to figure out this using some simple commands for branch creating?

Or maybe somebody have similar flow and can suggest something much better?

Answer (score 4):

A branch or tag name is in part just a short, human-readable name for one of those big ugly Git hash IDs you have seen.

There's really very little difference between a branch name like `X` and a tag name like `X`.  In fact, the key differences are:

- the *full name* of branch `X` is `refs/heads/X`;
- the *full name* of tag `X` is `refs/tags/X`;
- as a rule, a tag name should never change which hash ID it names, but a branch name normally *does* change over time, in a well-defined way: it always points to the latest commit added to the branch.

In fact, that's precisely *how* Git knows which commits are on the branch: the branch name `X`, which is really `refs/heads/X`, identifies the specific commit that is the tip of the branch.  That commit then refers back to its parent commit, which probably used to be the tip of the branch.  The parent commit refers to its own parent, and so on; and this is the history of the branch.

When Git tells you about a branch name, it strips off the leading `refs/heads/`.  When it tells you about a tag name, it strips off the leading `refs/tags/`.  (There are some exceptions but this is the usual rule.)

It's generally unwise to have two things whose short form is just `X` ... not because *Git* will get confused, but because *you* will.  Git has very precise—albeit rather convoluted—rules that always pick just one ... but not always the one you *meant*.  This is why you get the warning message.

Your choices are to *ignore* the warning, or work harder to avoid it.  To work harder, use Git's so-called *plumbing* commands.  These commands are meant to be used from scripts, and hence have very predictable and repeatable behavior, but they tend to require a lot of typing (which is OK, it's the computer doing the typing).

The plumbing command to create, delete, or update a reference—*reference* is the fancy long word for "branch, tag, or other such name"—is `git update-ref`, and it requires that you spell out `refs/heads/X` or `refs/tags/X` every time.  So you can write a script that checks for the existence of `refs/heads/whatever` and/or `refs/tags/whatever`, and creates or deletes the "other one".

To find out whether one exists, and if so get its value, use the plumbing command `git rev-parse` and spell out the full name of the reference.  The command will fail (and return a nonzero status, and normally print a message but you can suppress this) if the name does not exist, and will print out the hash ID if the name does exist.

Beware: when you delete a branch name, you also delete its reflog.  The reflog for a branch (or any reference, really) contains all the *previous* values that reference had, for the last 30 to 90 days or so (the numbers are a little complicated and can be tuned if you like).  Since tags don't normally move, their reflogs, if any, tend to be pretty dull: "this tag has always had value `0f39ca43...`"  Branches, however, *do* move, as we noted above, and their reflogs are full of "where this branch pointed yesterday" and such.

Comment: So, `git update-ref refs/heads/v3.2 v3.2; git tag -d v3.2`

Comment: @torek, thanks for explanation. Let me summarize. There are a few things that I want to clarify: 1) Do you suggest to use separate names for branches and tags? (e.g. feature-123 for branch and feature-123_tag for tag); 2) To check if tag already exists you suggest to use something like: `git rev-parse /refs/tags/feature-123_tag`. Is it correct?

Comment: @smart: It depends on what you want to do. For instance, a script named `git-convert-branch-to-tag` might check that its argument names one existing branch and zero existing tags, and would then create a tag and remove the branch; a script named `git-convert-tag-to-branch` would check the counterpart and do the counterpart. Or, one script, `git-switcheroo`, would take a name and figure out whether it's currently (branch,not-tag) or (not-branch,tag) and whichever it is now, switch it around. Placing scripts named these things in your `$PATH` will let you run `git <whatever>` to run them. Last,

Comment: it's just `refs/tags/feature-123_tag` for instance, not `/refs/tags/feature-123_tag`. If you use an unqualified name (e.g., `git rev-parse feature`), Git uses the six-step process in the linked documentation to figure out which name to use ... *except* that `git checkout` tries to use it as a branch name *first* (note that in the six step process, Git tries a *tag* name first, so `git checkout` disagrees with other Git commands as to which takes priority).

Comment: Oh, I see I didn't link to gitrevisions in the answer. The six step process is shown [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), near the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute following series of commands to get this done :

```
$ git checkout -b _tmp_<tag name> <tag name>
$ git tag -d <tag name>
$ git checkout -b <tag name>
$ git branch -d _tmp_<tag name>
```

What this will do is (in the same order)

- Create a branch with `_tmp_tag_branch` name referring to that
- delete that reference to the
- create another branch  referring to _tmp_tag_branch and thus to original  tag
- delete _tmp_tag_branch

**EDIT**

To make life easier you can add this to your `~/.gitconfig` as :

```
[alias]
    tag2branch = ! sh -c 'git checkout -b _tmp_$1 $1 && git tag -d $1 && git checkout -b $1 && git branch -d _tmp_$1' -
```

After that, you can simply do `$ git tag2branch <tag name>`

NOTE : This will only work on your system and for the user who owns `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: Is there any easier way?

Comment: maybe add them as an alisa ? will that work ? if yes I should edit the ans

Comment: what do you mean under alias?

Comment: Edited the ans, have a look